# Warning: error_log: failed to open stream: Permission denied

Tags: silverstripe

I've been working in Silverstripe 2.4.10. I'm still learning a lot about this content management system. I've been working on an update for the website and since I've put the update online I keep getting the error message in the admin panel of the CMS:

> Warning: error_log(../mysite/logs/warning_log.txt) [function.error-log]: 
>       failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/www.mysite.com/web/sapphire/dev/LogFileWriter.php on line 57

I have already tried to restore the website to the original code, since I've backed up the old code, but the problem still occurs. I've been looking all over the internet and can't find the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In silverstripe 2.4 the logging directory was setup with...

```
SS_Log::add_writer(new SS_LogFileWriter('/my/logfile/path'), SS_Log::ERR);
```

I can only guess that somehow that has been given the inappropriate path of mysite.

Searching for "SS_Log::add_writer" call or other log methods (see [docs for 2.4](https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-framework/blob/2.4/docs/en/topics/error-handling.md)) should help you find the code to fix it.